# Setting the modulation index (10% or 100%) for ISO/IEC 15693 programatically on Android

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693, modulation

Is possible set modulation index (10% or 100%) for ISO/IEC 15693 reading on Android devices programatically? Otherwise, is there a way to redo the tag through code without manually reconnecting the device again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Android does not provide an API for this (depending on the chipset lower layers of the NFC stack might be capable of changing this parameter though, but that's not necessarily the case and changing it would at least require you to change the Android OS).

Note, however, that an ISO/IEC 15693 compliant tag must be capable of decoding both 10% and 100% modulation indices (the same is true for the data coding mode).