# Android app for reading ISO15693 tags with 10% modulation depth

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693, modulation

I read a lot about how to develop an Android app that can read ISO15693 transponders. As far as that is all possible and there are a lot of ready-made apps in the PlayStore that do this task.

If you look at the reading process with an oscilloscope, you will notice that every available app, that I have downloaded, always uses 100% modulation for ISO15693 transponders.

We have developed a special "ISO15693" transponder that can be read wonderfully with our own readers.
These readers are all set to use 10% modulation.

I would like to know, is there a way to develop an Android app that can read ISO15693 transponders with 10% modulation depth?
Is there a parameter in any ISO15693 class that selects this setting?

I am very grateful for any help.

Comment: although this might have changed, there is a [similar question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787305/setting-the-modulation-index-10-or-100-for-iso-iec-15693-programatically-on)

Comment: depending on whether or not this has changed (that question is 4 years old) this might be a duplicate

Comment: I know this post. But because this post is already 4 years old, I have to ask this question again.
If the built-in RFID chip fully supports the ISO15693 protocol, it must support the 10% and 100% modulation depth.
And a lot can change in 4 years.

Comment: yes, i understand that, i didn't vote to mark this question as a duplicate, i merely stated it could be :)